# Jenkins configuration matrix limiter - subset of label

Tags: jenkins

I have a matrix configuration project in Jenkins which I would like to build under two axes:

label -> `rhel6`, `rhel7`

user-defined -> `default`, `devtoolset`, `clang`, `icc`

Some nodes are tagged as `rhel6` and some are tagged as `rhel7`.  All nodes have the `default`, `devtoolset` and `clang` compilers installed.  However, only some nodes have the `icc` compiler installed.  They have the `icc` label applied to them.  All of said nodes also have the `rhel7` label: there are no `rhel6` nodes with `icc`.  What should I put in the Combination Filter so that the `icc` row is only built on nodes with the `icc` label?  E.g., what I want to see is:

```
Configuration Matrix      rhel6  rhel7
                 default      O      O
              devtoolset      O      O
                   clang      O      O
                     icc      X      O
```

but the `icc` row cannot be built on just any `rhel7` node, only on the subset of `rhel7` nodes with the `icc` label.

I was able to get it technically functional by adding an additional label column and the following expression:

```
(label=="icc").implies(compiler=="icc") && (compiler=="icc").implies(label=="icc")
```

but that generates the following:

```
Configuration Matrix        icc  rhel6  rhel7
                 default      X      O      O
              devtoolset      X      O      O
                   clang      X      O      O
                     icc      O      X      X
```

which is definitely not as clean as it should be.  Any ideas?